# C# 7 Expression Bodied Constructors

Tags: .net, c#-7.0

In C# 7, how do I write an Expression Bodied Constructor like this using 2 parameters.

```
public Person(string name, int age)
{
  Name = name;
  Age = age;
}
```

Comment: This idea has been brought up and ignored numerous times on UserVoice.  Please go vote so the idea can get some traction.  It's 2017 - C# should have better shorthand for dependency injection!  https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17225666-automatic-constructor-parameter-setters

Comment: @pbarranis, [records, which offer an even better choice of syntax than your user voice suggestion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39) - `public class Person(string name, int age, int height);` - are being considered for C# 8.0.

Answer (score 73):

A way to do this is to use a tuple and a deconstruction to allow multiple assignments in one expression:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Age { get; }

    public Person(string name, int age) => (Name, Age) = (name, age);
}
```

As of C# 7.1 (introduced with Visual Studio 2017 Update 3), the compiler code will now optimise away the actual construction and deconstruction of the tuple. So this approach has no performance overhead when compared with "longhand" assignment.

Comment: This is evil. I'm using C# 7.1 and I just can't unsee this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, in what way is it evil? As if C# 7.1, I've started using this as it seems like a neat solution to me.

Comment: @DavidArno He probably thought it was a little bit evil-genius given how many CPU cycles are being used under the hood just for the sake of elegant syntax.  I decided to create a little app to do a side-by-side comparison, and the tuple syntax above doubled the amount of time necessary to new-up the object.  IMHO that's actually impressive and speaks to how performant tuples are.  For 99.999% of developers, I'd say the perf difference here is inconsequential.

Comment: I could **not** figure this out for more than one property. Thanks!