# Understanding this expression body definition

Tags: c#

I came across this code:

```
    private class Node
    {
        public Node(T t) => (Next, Data) = (null, t);

        public Node Next { get; set; }
        public T Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Can someone explain what this means in the constructor ?

```
public Node(T t) => (Next, Data) = (null, t);
```

I am not sure what this means

```
(Next, Data) = (null, t);
```

Comment: That's technically called an [expression-bodied constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#constructors), see for example [C# 7 Expression Bodied Constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974143/c-sharp-7-expression-bodied-constructors).

Comment: @dxiv: Overall it's an expression-bodied constructor, but that `(Next, Data) = (null, t);` part isn't specific to expression-bodied constructors - it just happens to often be used with them.

Comment: @JonSkeet Right of course, thanks for setting that straight.

Answer (score 5):

It's a mixture of:

- A tuple literal (the `(null, t)` part)
- A [deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct#deconstructing-a-tuple) (the `(Next, Data) = ...` part)

It's effectively this:

```cs
public Node(T t)
{
    Next = null;
    Data = t;
}
```

... but written as a single assignment expression, which means you can use it as an expression-bodied member.

It's odd the first time you see it, but when you're used to it it's a *wonderful* way of writing simple constructors that just copy parameter values into fields and properties.

Comment: Why couldn't they do this ? `public Node(T t) => Next =null; Data = t;` or is that an invalid expression body ?

Comment: @MistyD: Yes, it's invalid because that's two statements. You'd need a regular block body for that. And yes, you absolutely can do that... it's just more verbose.

Comment: Does it have any kind of performance hit when you do it with deconstruction or it is the same performance like the old way?

Comment: @EfthymiosKalyviotis: I believe the compiler actually recognizes this particular pattern and emits exactly the same IL as the "old-style" code.

Comment: Of curiosity, I tried to de-compile both cases with JetBrains DotPeek and I took slightly different results (although I didn't know how to compare the IL).  https://imgur.com/a/a1UU25L